# How can we get previous and current value of a Signal based Input in Angular v17?

Tags: angular17, angular-signals, angular-input

In earlier versions of Angular, ngOnChanges provides [SimpleChange](https://angular.io/api/core/SimpleChange) which is helpful in getting previousValue and currentValue of an @Input property.

I want this same functionality in Signal based Inputs but I couldn't find any way to get previous value of Input. Is there any way around this?

I read about using @angular/core/rxjs-interop to convert the signal to Observable and use [pairwise](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise) but pairwise emits on the second and subsequent emissions from the source Observable, but not on the first emission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was rather simple. Apparently, Angular signal input still supports the SimpleChanges interface. So we can use the same old way of ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) to get the previous value.

But, I've heard that Angular team is thinking of deprecating ngOnChanges in future. So not sure how future compatible this code is gonna be. Any suggestions are welcome.

Here is an example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dkoxpz?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: `ngOnChanges` probably won't get deprecated but rather won't even exist Signal components (as we won't have any `@Input()`).

Comment: But then what would be the way to get previous value of signal input in a Signal component?

Comment: Here is one code comment where deprecation is being suggested - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/definition.ts#L79-L84

Comment: This is a very old comment, see https://twitter.com/synalx/status/1743413419754090997

Comment: Oh okay, that clears some things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries like `ng-extension` provide helper functions to this kind of purposes.

For example [`computedPrevious`](https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/signals/computed-previous/) or [`computedExtended`](https://ngxtension.netlify.app/utilities/signals/computed/) allow access to a previous value.

import { extendedComputed } from 'ngxtension/computed';

```
const multiplier = signal(2);
const count = signal(1);

const result = extendedComputed<number>((previousValue) => {
  // only compute when multiplier is even
  if (multiplier() % 2 === 0) {
    return count() * multiplier();
  }
  return previousValue;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this definitely helps. Although I feel it should be baked in the InputSignal itself.